# How to resolve warnings when executing wordpress's xmlrpc.xml?

Tags: php, wordpress, warnings

I installed Wordpress on unix hosting provider and now I see warnings when executing xmlrpc.xml?

[This is where I see warnings](http://www.romankagan.com/xmlrpc.php)

Greatly appreciate in advance for helping me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warnings are just that: warnings. They tell you that something might be broken but it's not enough to cause the script to fail.

The real problem is the fatal error: `Fatal error: Class 'IXR_Server' not found`

This indicates that WordPress is not installed correctly.

Also, you shouldn't show error messages on production sites. Use error logging instead. [This guide should get you started](http://www.addedbytes.com/drafts/php-ini-guide/php-ini-guide-error-handling-and-logging/).